# Infinite loop in SwiftUI layout

Tags: swiftui

Due to limitations of SwiftUI VSplitView, and to preserve the appearance of the old C++/AppKit app I'm porting to SwiftUI, I rolled my own pane divider. It worked well on macOS 11, but after updating to macOS 12, it now triggers an infinite loop somewhere. Running the code below in an Xcode playground works for a short while, but if you wiggle the mouse up and down, after a few seconds it will get caught in an infinite loop. Curiously, running in the macOS Playgrounds App, no infinite loop occurs.

Any advice on diagnosing what is causing the infinite loop and how to avoid it?

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var position: Double = 50
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Color.red.frame(maxHeight: position)
            Rectangle().fill(Color.yellow).frame(height: 8)
            .gesture(DragGesture().onChanged { position = max(0, position + $0.translation.height) })
            Color.blue
        }.frame(width: 500, height:500)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific on your question?

Comment: More specific on how to reproduce the problem? Or more specific on what I am trying to do?

Comment: Are you just looking for more information on an infinite loop?

Comment: I'm trying to implement something that behaves similar to VSplitView, (with a different appearance, and the ability to track its position in the document format). This code achieved that in macOS 11, and works for a little while in macOS 12 before hanging. I would like to understand why it is hanging and fix that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an infinite loop. The runtime error is pretty clear. You are producing a negative frame height which isn't allowed. Ironically, after implementing a "fix", I can't get your code to break again. I suggest clamping your variable so that this can't accidentally happen. The other thing this does is guarantee that your max position is the max height possible of the view you are changing. Obviously, I wouldn't hard code these numbers in use.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var position: Double = 50
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Text(position.description)
            Color.red.frame(maxHeight: position)
            Rectangle().fill(Color.yellow).frame(height: 8)
                .gesture(DragGesture().onChanged { position = (position + $0.translation.height).clamped(to: 0...250) })
            Color.blue
        }.frame(width: 500, height:500)
    }
}

extension Comparable {
    func clamped(to limits: ClosedRange<Self>) -> Self {
        return min(max(self, limits.lowerBound), limits.upperBound)
    }
}
```

Comment: max(0, position + $0.translation.height) should guarantee it is non-negative, no?

Comment: I would agree, but it is unlimited on the top, while your view is not. I have seen this before, but I can't remember where, but I think things get confused as a result. The clamping absolutely prevents this. You can also set percentages, so you can go 100 either way. Just throw a `GeometryReader` around your views, and use percentages of the hight from that.

Answer (score 1):

Using .location in the stack coordinate space instead of .translation avoids the problem, whatever it was. The following works as desired with no infinite loop.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var position: Double = 50

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Color.red.frame(width: 500, height: position)
            PaneDivider(position: $position)
            Color.blue
        }
        .frame(width: 500, height:500)
        .coordinateSpace(name: "stack")
    }
}

struct PaneDivider: View {
    @Binding var position: Double
 
    var body: some View {
        Color.yellow.frame(height: 8)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 1, coordinateSpace: .named("stack"))
            .onChanged { position = max(0, $0.location.y) }
            )
    }
}
```